# Create nested loop in a dynamic way in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this: `foo = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [6,7,8]})` and a list of columns `list_of_columns = ['a','b']` of `foo`.

The `list_of_columns` are dynamically selected by the user, so it can be `['a','b']` but it can also be `['a','c']` or `['c']` or `['a','b','c']` etc

I would like for every `column` in the `list_of_columns` to create (nested) `for` loops and query the dataframe in the following way:

In case `list_of_columns = ['a','b']` the the loop would be like this:

```
for a in foo.a.unique():
    for b in foo.b.unique():
        print(foo.query(f'a=={a} and b=={b}'))
```

In case `list_of_columns = ['a']` the the loop would be like this:

```
for a in foo.a.unique():
    print(foo.query(f'a=={a}'))
```

In case `list_of_columns = ['a','b','c']` the the loop would be like this:

```
for a in foo.a.unique():
    for b in foo.b.unique():
        for c in foo.c.unique():
            print(foo.query(f'a=={a} and b=={b} and c=={c}'))
```

Is there a way to programmatically achieve that in python ?

Comment: Your input DataFrame is invalid, do you have a NaN?

Comment: recursive function with a single loop. You remove 'a' from list and call this function recursively with smaller list for every element in 'a'. When the list is empty print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, it looks like you want to loop over the unique combinations?

But as you then query for valid ones, you obtain a lot of empty DataFrames.
If you do not need those, a much simpler and more efficient version would be:

```
for _,g in foo.groupby(list_of_columns):
    print('---')
    print(g)
```

output:

```
---
   a  b  c
0  1  4  6
---
   a  b  c
1  2  5  7
---
   a  b  c
2  3  6  8
```

In comparison, the output of your nested loop:

```
---
   a  b  c
0  1  4  6
---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
---
   a  b  c
1  2  5  7
---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
---
   a  b  c
2  3  6  8
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), to handle the "nested" loops:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

foo = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [6, 7, 8]})

list_of_columns = ['a', 'b']
for p in product(*(foo[col].unique() for col in list_of_columns)):
    query = " and ".join(f"{c}=={u}" for c, u in zip(list_of_columns, p))
    print(foo.query(query))
    print("--")
```

**Output**

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  6
--
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
--
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
--
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
--
   a  b  c
1  2  5  7
--
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
--
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
--
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
--
   a  b  c
2  3  6  8
--
```